# Trigger build if commit messages contain text

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-commit, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Is there any way for a VSTS build definition to interrogate the git commit messages and only trigger if any of the commit messages contain pre-defined text?

Alternatively is it possible to have a task within the build definition that will stop the build if the predefined text does not exist in any commit message?

Comment: Do you solve the issue with jessehouwing's solution?

Comment: Yes, I've just marked it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a two-part question:

1. No, there is no filter on commit messages.
2. Yes, this is easier to do, though it's not guaranteed that a build triggers on every commit, as multiple commits can be pushed in groups. And Server side batching may batch commits when a build is in progress.

You can insert a small script that executes `git log -1 --pretty=%B` and inspects the output; and then uses the special logging format to fail the build. For example, in PowerShell this would log an error and fail the build:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Build token missing, aborting."
Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Cancelled"
```

For more details on the special commands, see: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

The git command only works in the Build pipeline, the information is not available in the release pipeline unless you actually clone the repo during the release as well.

You could set the build version to include some kind of postfix as part of the build and then use that information in the release pipeline. The same magic commands include one to set the Build.BuildNumber:

```
 Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]1.1.7-Release"
```

Then in your release pipeline, check the version number.

Or use the [Trigger a Release](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergiibomko.vsts-trigger) task in your build definition and make its execution conditional based on your output of the PowerShell you've already created.